# Question about Create oAuth2PermissionGrant (a delegated permission grant)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I followed this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I can successful request the list api after add permission "
Directory.Read.All" to the application, while the create api returns an error

```
"error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-11-15T08:54:50",
        "request-id": "46986851-590c-4687-b909-918e9d233f07",
        "client-request-id": "46986851-590c-4687-b909-918e9d233f07"
    }
}
```

is there any other permission required or some additional operations needed?

Comment: Hello @CYLong, May i know the method of authenctication you are following for the above request ? like client_credentials/implicit/authcode?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT  implicit.But in my opinion, the method doesn't matter how to create permission.

Comment: I was able to successfully able to do it from Graph Explorer using the admin account to create the permission.

Comment: Can you also please try the same operation from [**Graph_Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and see if it succeeds?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I didn't find this API in  Graph Explorer

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT what permissions does the admin account have?

Comment: ,it has global admin access .. You can click on th link of graph explorer, in the left side you can sign in with your account then on right side there is bar you can click on get then from the drop down select post and paste the api request beside post ,provide request body and click send .

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as the Create requests requires `Directory.ReadWrite.All`. You app seems to have only `Directory.Read.All` which is not enough for doing objects writes.

Trying adding `Directory.ReadWrite.All` to your app and trying again. Make sure it is granted by admin on Azure AD portal.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @CYLong Please share the error message from Graph API after adding Directory.ReadWrite.All. Include the request id and timestamp as in the question body. If you have this permission, your request should go through authorization unless there is a specific issue with your tenant or application.